# Check trend for non-normal data?

Tags: statistics

I have data which is non-normally distributed time series. I want to find whether with time its increasing or decreasing. How will I check it. Earlier I thought of using t-test and linear fit. But I think t-test is for normally distributed data.

Please help, I am not very strong in statistics.

Comment: I wouldn't even try to think about this without more information than you've given.

Comment: Ohh..I have this mean rainfall data. It is not a normal distribution. I just want to know whether the rainfall is increasing with time or decreasing. Thanks.

Comment: What statistical method should be used might depend on some information that is not yet here.  I think this question might fare better on stats.stackexchange.com than here.